# HID-device not recognized (anymore) in 1 certain USB port

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, hid, usb-hid

In my current project, I'm working with an IPC (Industrial Windows 7 Ultimate PC), and 1 or more Hall sensors. These probes measure the magnetic field strength of a newly produced magnet, and return the value (Tesla) in a string.

This setup works with an self written c# application, using the manufacturer's library and a Profinet library, to send the results to a PLC.

Recently, one of the two probes no longer connects. I’ve received a Windows notification that the connected USB device [is no longer recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BGmQ.png). Device Manager shows one of the probes, which originally appeared as an HID device, is now an unknown USB device.

After more investigation I found the device now is recognized only when on one certain port. All other ports result in an unknown device. However, I can move the other probe into every port I wish, and it works. Also on my laptop, the affected certain probe works on every port.

I was in contact with the manufacturer of the probe and they told me that they never had issues like this before. I also connected the IPC to Internet, and installed all updates.

Microsoft recommends uninstalling the driver and rebooting the system, but this doesn’t solve my issue.

Comment: Probably a connector issue on the original PC; one USB port connector could be out of spec. What happens if you put a port expander on the good port and run both probes through it?